# Having TKinter GUI in seperate .py file and binding functions to buttons in the GUI file

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm trying to teach myself to code in python after programming in C# for a few years now. I find the transition quite hard so far, but hope that with some persistence I will eventually understand python

My problem: after experimenting with programs like wxglade and wxformbuilder I was charmed by the way those programs provide you with a nice seperate GUI file so that you can put all your functions in a seperate main file. However, I would like to apply the same principle to tkinter GUIs, but I can't figure it out, nor can I find documentation about it.

Let's say I have two files:
GUI.py:

```
from tkinter import * 

class BotGUI:

    def __init__(self, master):
        # ***** Creation of the frame for all items to be on *****
        xWidth=800
        yWidth=500
        margin=100
        outer_frame=Frame(master, width=xWidth, height=yWidth, bg='lightgray')
        outer_frame.pack(ipadx=margin, ipady=margin)
        button1 = Button(outer_frame, text = "Print something", command = printcommand)
        button1.pack()

    #Virtual event handlers
    def printcommand(self, event):
        event.Skip()
```

and then a file called Main.py:

```
from tkinter import *
import GUI

class GUI_Functions(GUI.BotGUI):

    def __init__(self,parent):
        GUI.BotGUI.__init__(self, parent)

    def printcommand(self, event):
        print("The bind was successful!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    GUI_Frame = GUI.BotGUI(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

The above code results in the error:

```
NameError: global name 'printcommand' is not defined
```

I just cannot figure out how to get this working for a tkinter GUI. Hope someone can help me out a bit!

(GUI creation is so much easier in C# with visual studio :( )

Comment: You shouldn't provide an answer to your question in the question post itself. If your issue is resolved please either select the answer that solved the issue or provide your own answer _as_ an answer using the bottom-most textbox.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Nae, I am new to participating on stack overflow (up to now, only have been leeching :p). I have removed the answer from my first posted and found the answer button at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error because Python doesn't know where to find the the function `printcommand`.

First import the file `Main.py` so you can use it in `GUI.py`.

`import Main.py`

The problem now is that the method `printcommand` is an *instance method* meaning you need to have an object to call it.

To accomplish this.

- Create an instance of the `GUIFunctions` class and reference the method using the object

`guifuncs = Main.GUIFunctions(master)`

`command = guifuncs.printcommand`

Note: you must prefix references to Main.py with `Main` with the import syntax used above.

I hope this helps you and if you have any further questions please feel free to post a comment below!

Answer (score 0):

Python cannot find a global function called "printcommand", and indeed there is no global function "printcommand". You have to tell `button1` that the callback command is a local function by adding `self.` to the callback definition. It should look like this:
`command = self.printcommand`

This will lead to another problem, that the button callback does not pass an event back. I solved this by removing the event argument such that the printcommand function in GUI.py looked like this:

```
def printcommand(self):
    pass
```

If you do need to pass a value to the callback function [this page at Effbot](http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-callbacks.htm) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

As answered by Micheal I was lacking the "import Main" in my GUI.py file, after I got that running I found some other small faults in the code so please find below the code that I used to get this running:

GUI.py file:

```
from tkinter import * 
import Main


class BotGUI:

    def __init__(self, master):
        # ***** Import the guifunctions from the Main.py file
        guifuncs = Main.GUI_Functions(master)

        # ***** Creation of the frame for all items to be on *****
        xWidth=800
        yWidth=500
        margin=100
        outer_frame=Frame(master, width=xWidth, height=yWidth, bg='lightgray')
        outer_frame.pack(ipadx=margin, ipady=margin)
        button1 = Button(outer_frame, text = "Print something", command = guifuncs.printcommand)
        button1.pack()
```

and the Main.py file:

```
from tkinter import * 
import GUI


class GUI_Functions():

    def __init__(self,parent):
        pass

    def printcommand(self):
        print("The bind was successful!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    GUI_Frame = GUI.BotGUI(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Thanks to Micheal for pointing out the problem! Also thanks to Alex for providing the useful link to effbot.org!

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will help.

Create a file called 'guiFactory.py'

```
def createButton(self, Button, text, command, highlightbackground, compound, x, y):
    self.nav_button = Button(self, text =text, command=command, highlightbackground=highlightbackground, compound=compound) 
    self.nav_button.place(x = x, y = y)
```

In your main application file.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import StringVar, IntVar, messagebox, OptionMenu, Button, Label, filedialog as fd 
import guiFactory

class MainApplication(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent

        # Canvas Size
        parent.geometry("300x350")
        self.configure(bg="#3E4149")
        parent.title("Test Application") 

        # Submit Button
        def convertFilesHandler():
            print("Do Something")

        # buttons
        convertBtn = guiFactory.createButton(self, Button, "Convert", convertFilesHandler, "#3E4149", "center", 200, 250)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    MainApplication(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```